# Format used by GDAL ReadRaster

Tags: raster, gdal, java

I'm trying to display a GeoTIFF raster in a Java SWT widget. Here is a sample of the original TIFF file, opened in QGIS:

[image]

I'm using GDAL to get the information out of the image, but I'm struggling to understand the data format GDAL is using in the bytearray it fills. After a few attempts involving nearly a dozen conversions between AWT data structures, Buffers, Image objects, int/byte arrays and whatnot, I'm at a point where I can see the data directly, by getting the raw information into a bytearray with the following minimal number of conversions:

```
int w = scrSize.width;
int h = scrSize.height;
int[] bandSelection = new int[]{1,2,3};
int arrSize = h*w*bandSelection.length;
byte[] array = new byte[arrSize];
                    
Dataset raster = gdal.Open(<file path>, gdalconstConstants.GA_ReadOnly);
int returnVal = raster.ReadRaster(0, 0, w*2, h*2, w, h, gdalconstConstants.GPI_RGB, array, bandSelection); 

System.out.println("ReturnVal "+returnVal);

BufferedImage bIm = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                    
                    
for (int y=0; y<h; ++y) {
    for (int x=0; x<w; ++x) {
        int index = (y * w * 3) + (x *3);
        int rgb = ((array[index] & 0xFF) << 16) |
                  ((array[index] & 0xFF) <<  8) |
                  ((array[index] & 0xFF)      ) |
                  0xFF000000;
        bIm.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
    }
}
ImageData idata = GeoUtils.convertToSWT(bIm); 
Image image = new Image(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay(), idata);
ImageDescriptor imageDesc = ImageDescriptor.createFromImage(image);
```

This gives a return code of 0, indicating no issues with the function call itself, and loads `array` with the data contained in the TIFF file. I've also managed to both show that data on screen by doing the following jumps with that data:

```
Image image = new Image(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay(), new ByteArrayInputStream(dStream.array()));
ImageDescriptor imageDesc = ImageDescriptor.createFromImage(image);
```

And then using that `ImageDescriptor` on an SWT widget.

The issue with this approach is that what I see is not an RGB image, but 9 separate grayscale images (The three top, middle and bottom layers are clearly different colour channels, but I can't see any differences between left/middle/right images other than some minor artefacting in the corners), as if ReadRaster was dumping the different channels separately several times into the byte array, instead of using the usual RGBRGBRGB order, like in the following image.

[image: GDAL output]

I managed to replicate this behaviour by taking that bytearray and generating ad-hoc BMP file headers for it and then saving it to a file (I ran out of ideas and had to try). The results were the following (This is a different map, but the issue remains. The images have distortion because I had to get all RGBA bands to make buffer lines divisible by 4 for the BMP and it processed the alpha as a colour):

[image: Image from GDAL Dataset data]

I can open the file just fine, and I can also load that into the widget, but the data is not correctly laid out. Further messing with the bytearray using the loops in the first block of code caused some increasingly interesting, but decreasingly useful images to be generated and stored.

As a last ditch attempt I've tried changing my approach, loading the data into a RGB integer array instead, with the following:

```
int returnVal2 = raster.ReadRaster(0, 0, w*2, h*2, w, h, gdalconstConstants.GPI_RGB, pixels, bandSelection);
```

But that call keeps returning 3, indicating some sort of issue. Debugging that function call with anything more sophisticated than blindly throwing different parameters at it seems impossible: I can't load that information into an integer array, and at this point, even if I could, I have doubts it would give a usable image, or any different result for that matter.

I've looked at the documentation available online (mainly the [GDAL API reference](https://gdal.org/java/org/gdal/gdal/Dataset.html) and I've spent the past two days looking for a way to make this work, and I'm out of ideas. I'm fairly confident it's not a file format issue (I have the same issue with standard GeoTIFFs and COGs), there are no sources that dive deeper into this than quoting the API or copying the same few examples, no document ever mentions *how* exactly that bytearray is laid out, I've ran out of sources to read, examples to get ideas from and things to try, and I've spent the past two hours just blindly changing things to see what happened, without any hope of this ever working.

How do I go from GDAL Dataset to SWT Image using the GDAL Java bindings?

Comment: GDAL stands for "geospatial data abstraction library". Maybe users are not supposed to deal directly with the bytearrays. GDAL Java bindings are not so widely used and it may be hard to find usage examples. Maybe the GeoTools GDAL plugin code https://github.com/geosolutions-it/imageio-ext/tree/master/plugin/gdal could give some ideas.

Comment: The short answer to your title is "It uses all of them." But that isn't what you want to know. This is the reason for the One question per Question policy, as stated in the [Tour].

Comment: @user30184 If you look at the Java bindings for GDAL, you'll see the only thing the RasterReader function can do is to modify the provided short/byte/int/long/double array with the data. I don't think there's anything else I can do with the bindings to get that image into the application.

Comment: @Vince That absolutely is the answer to the title, but not to the actual question I was asking. The other additional questions in my post were related to the original one and were a way of getting additional information or clues that may be of help, but I have edited it anyway to comply with the one question policy.

Comment: I do not really know what these demos do but maybe they are worth having a look https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/tree/master/swig/java/apps/.

Comment: In my experience, most rasters are BSQ (band sequential) or BIL (band interleaved by line), not BIP (band interleaved by pixel), so I wouldn't expect "RGBRGBRGB" more like RRRRGGGGBBBB or RRGGBBRRGGBB. this is especially true if the underlying data is tiled (as in a COG). I expect the API will tell you what to expect. In order to get BIL I once needed to cache a row of tiles and align them for BIL export. I suspect that using the bytes in other than the actual encoding is corrupting the result, but this may be a RTFM on the doc.